# How to enable CORS on IIS Manager of Windows 10?

Tags: windows, iis, cors

I've created an HTTPS server using IIS Manager (Windows 10). Now, I want this server to support CORS requests.

I've read some information. For example, 
[this](https://enable-cors.org/server_iis7.html) link says that I have to create a file web.config in the directory. Unfortunately, it didn't work out.
[This](http://www.melvinswebstuff.com/blog/2015/01/02/enable-cors-iisexpress/) link says that I should edit some config files, but I don't find them on my machine.

Comment: are you using iis express or iis manager ? when you not worrking,what is not working ? https://enable-cors.org/server_iis7.html should work  .you would not have added the config in the correct place

Comment: I use IIS Manager. I put this XML in web.config file, and put it in my project directory, and it didn't help.

Comment: I have the same problem. I'm using IIS 10 with IIS Manager.  When I look in [IIS CORS module Configuration Reference][1], I don't see anything at all about how to install the CORS module.


  [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/cors-module/cors-module-configuration-reference

Answer (score 34):

I had a similar issue recently. Most tutorial/documentation only suggests adding custom headers in the configuration. But this does not tell IIS to handle the CORS Pre-flight request by itself.

To do so, you must install the [CORS Module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-cors-module) in IIS and add some configuration in the web.config file, as explained here: [IIS CORS module Configuration Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/cors-module/cors-module-configuration-reference#cors-configuration)

I recently used this to Reverse Proxy to a REST API and handling the CORS only in IIS so that I don't have to rebuild my project to change CORS settings.

Comment: I also updated the following resource with a better explanation: https://enable-cors.org/server_iis7.html

Comment: The link you provided adds a <cors> element to the web.config and that is not working on IIS 8.5 at least. Do you know which version of IIS it would work with, if it works at all? Thanks!

Comment: Found it. Need to install this - https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-cors-module - prior to using the <cors> element in web.config.

Comment: Sorry @ShivaNaru. Just added the link in my answer!

Comment: Do I just need to add <cors enabled="true" failUnlistedOrigins="true"> or the whole section?

Comment: I got a reject for signature verification with IIS 10.  I had to download from this link I found in the log file instead: download.microsoft.com/download/2/F/2/2F259559-FC43-4B2C-B53F-DED3E9950912/IISCORS_amd64.msi

Comment: This worked. I simply added `<cors enabled="true" failUnlistedOrigins="true"> <add origin="*" /> </cors>` to `Web.config`

Answer (score -1):

Try to add this into :

```
    <system.webServer>
        <modules>
            <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>
```